# Создание универсального кода для web/mobile в starling

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe-air

Суть в следующем. starling / AIR / as3.
В мобильной версии загружаю всю внешнюю графику:

```
 assets.enqueue(appDir.resolvePath("head/atlasVikings.png"));
 assets.enqueue(appDir.resolvePath("head/atlasVikings.xml"));
```

Для Web версии пытаюсь нужно сделать тоже самое. Следующий вариант не работает...

```
package other {
    public class EmbeddedAssets {

    [Embed(source="../../bin/head/atlasVikings.png")]
    public static const art:Class;

    [Embed(source = "../../bin/head/atlasVikings.xml", mimeType = "application/octet-stream")]
    public static const art_xml:Class;


    }
}
```

Загружаю:

```
assets.enqueue(EmbeddedAssets);
```

Добавляю следующим образом

```
var textureLoader:Texture= assets.getTexture("preloader_bg");
_loader = new Image(textureLoader);
```

Получаю ошибку Texture cannot be null

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена.
Имена файлов должны совпадать

```
[Embed(source="../../bin/head/atlasVikings.png")]
public static const atlasVikings:Class;

[Embed(source = "../../bin/head/atlasVikings.xml", mimeType = "application/octet-stream")]
public static const atlasVikings_xml:Class;
```